# Problema con drag and drop

Tags: php, javascript

Buenas, la verdad no se como formular la pregunta, lo que me sucede es que cuando intento subir un archivo con la herramienta, mi navegador tiene como un crash de memoria, de verdad no se explicarlo. Acá esta la función en Java Script.

```
            $(function(){
      var dragEntrada = document.getElementById('dragEntrada');

//tengo problemas cuando coloco esta función      
var upload = function(files){
        var formData = new FormData(),
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        x;
        for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x+1) {
          formData.append('file[]', files[x]);
        }
        xhr.onload = function(){
          var data = this.responseText;
          console.log(data);
        }

        xhr.open('post', 'upload.php');
        xhr.send(formData);
      }
   // 
      dragEntrada.ondrop = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.className = 'dragEntrada';
        upload(e.dataTransfer.files);
      }

      dragEntrada.ondragover = function(){
        this.className = 'dragEntrada dragover';
        return false;
      }

      dragEntrada.ondragleave = function(){
        this.className = 'dragEntrada';
        return false;
      }

    }());
```

Si necesitan otra parte del código estaré pendiente para colocarlo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en:

```
 for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x+1)
```

Esto genera un bucle infinito porque la instrucción `x+1` le suma `1` a `x` pero el resultado no se lo asigna a la variable `x` por lo que esta variable siempre tiene valor `0` y nunca sale del bucle.

Cámbialo por:

```
 for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++)
```

```js
var x=0;
x+1;
console.log('Valor después de x+1: ' + x);
x++;
console.log('Valor después de x++: ' + x);
```